# ActiveRecord find by model's array attribute containing a value (not association array)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails model with an attribute that is an array of data values (strings). I would like to do an ActiveRecord find that returns any records whose array contains a specific value.  Is  there a way to do this with ActiveRecord that would make it more performant than iteration?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Rails serializes arrays using YAML by default, it's difficult to do a "contains a value" query.

If your values are unique and part of a fixed set, (e.g. a `roles` column with `['User', 'Admin', 'Guest']`), you could do something like this:

```
User.where("roles ilike '%\n- Guest\n%'")
```

since that will match on the YAML of `---\n- User\n- Admin\n Guest\n`.

Alternatively, you could use the native array type in Postgres. In Rails 3, you would need to use the [activerecord-postgres-array gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-postgres-array) (though I don't know how well maintained this is); in Rails 4, it's supported natively.

You would set up your column as such:

```
t.string :roles_array, :array => true, :length => 30
```

Then you could query against it:

```
User.where("'Guest' = ANY(roles_array)")
```

Comment: AWESOME!  Perfect, just the kind of thing i was looking for, and this little trick will surely come in handy in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: I like the former method because it's DB agnostic, but is the latter more performant?

Comment: Since you can add an index for the array column, I would assume the array method would be faster; however, your dataset may need to get pretty large to notice much of a difference.

Comment: How would one modify this if you aren't looking for an exact match but a fuzzy match?